# Unable to get mongodb started

Tags: ubuntu, mongodb

I have been trying to uninstall and reinstall `mongodb`, but it keeps failing.

```
campagnollo@campagnollo-Galago-Pro:~$ sudo systemctl status mongodb
● mongodb.service - High-performance, schema-free document-oriented >database
   Loaded: loaded (/etc/systemd/system/mongodb.service; enabled; vendor preset: enabled)
   Active: failed (Result: exit-code) since Mon 2019-11-11 22:16:54 EST; 50s ago
 Main PID: 10370 (code=exited, status=2)

Nov 11 22:16:54 campagnollo-Galago-Pro systemd[1]: Started High-performance, schema-free document-ori
Nov 11 22:16:54 campagnollo-Galago-Pro mongod[10370]: Error reading config file: No such file or dire
Nov 11 22:16:54 campagnollo-Galago-Pro mongod[10370]: try '/usr/bin/mongod --help' for more informati
Nov 11 22:16:54 campagnollo-Galago-Pro systemd[1]: mongodb.service: Main process exited, code=exited,
Nov 11 22:16:54 campagnollo-Galago-Pro systemd[1]: mongodb.service: Failed with result 'exit-code'.
```

Answer (score 0):

What is the version of your Ubuntu?
Have you checked the content of the mongodb.conf file? 
Check `/lib/systemd/system/mongod.service` to see where config flag is pointing to.